# Hiding header of UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I have TableView with invisible header. I already tried unsuccessfully to hide the header with:

`tableView.tableHeaderView = .init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))`

`tableView.tableHeaderView?.removeFromSuperview()`

`tableView.tableHeaderView = nil`

But I found out that if you call a multitask or manually change the theme to dark/light, this header disappears

[Here is an example](https://youtu.be/LNHqN8wvXNk)

**So, is this a bug, or I missing something?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works perfectly

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = .init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for table header

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

Also if you want to hide header for section then you can achieve with below tableview delegate methods.

```
func tableView(_: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}

func tableView(_: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection _: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in my case, and I already configured my sections

Answer (score 0):

You can use without frame

```
 tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView()
```

Comment: Didn't work, header still appears

Comment: please share your class file code then it will be easily to understand what you are doing

Answer (score -1):

**This Works For me**

```
var frame = CGRect.zero
frame.size.height = .leastNormalMagnitude
tableViewname.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: frame)
```

also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72389011/18202989) will work in single line [answer by @getmemd]